# clip path formed by a set of squares in a group

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this [situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cExGX.png) , can I group more elements under a clip path in d3? I would like to have more squares that make the line green. I tried various things but none of them worked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.dot {
  fill: white;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
//def variabili
var width = 960,
height = 500;
//data
var data = [
  [new Date(2001, 0, 1), 1],
  [new Date(2002, 0, 1), 2],
  [new Date(2003, 0, 1), 2],
  [new Date(2004, 0, 1), 3],
  [new Date(2005, 0, 1), 4],
  [new Date(2006, 0, 1), 5]
];
//margin
var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
//assi
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(2001, 0, 1), new Date(2006, 0, 1)])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 6])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[1]); });
//Append svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



var defs = svg.append("defs");

    defs.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "area")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", 250)
    .attr("y", 220)
    .attr("width", 150)
 .attr("height", 100);

//plot axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

//plot rect
svg.append("rect")
.attr("x", 250)
.attr("y", 220)
.attr("width", 150)
.attr("height", 100)
.style("fill", "yellow");

//plot line
svg.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.style("stroke", "red")
.attr("d", line);

//plot line overlay
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#area)")
.style("stroke", "green")
.style("stroke-width", "3")
    .attr("d", line);


</script>
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you are asking.  If you want more clip-paths just create more clip-paths...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to make your clip-paths data driven:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  .dot {
    fill: white;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    //def variabili
    var width = 960,
      height = 500;
     //data
    var data = [
      [new Date(2001, 0, 1), 1],
      [new Date(2002, 0, 1), 2],
      [new Date(2003, 0, 1), 2],
      [new Date(2004, 0, 1), 3],
      [new Date(2005, 0, 1), 4],
      [new Date(2006, 0, 1), 5]
    ];
     //margin
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
     //assi
    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .domain([new Date(2001, 0, 1), new Date(2006, 0, 1)])
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 6])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("monotone")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d[0]);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d[1]);
      });

     //Append svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 
    var clips = [
      {
        x: 250,
        y: 250,
        width: 150,
        height: 150
      },{
        x: 100,
        y: 300,
        width: 50,
        height: 50
      },{
        x: 700,
        y: 100,
        width: 50,
        height: 50
      }
      
    ];    
    
    var defs = svg.append("defs");

    defs.selectAll("clipPath")
      .data(clips)
      .enter()
      .append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", function(d,i){
        return "area-" + i;
      })
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d){
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d){
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("width", function(d){
        return d.width;
      })
      .attr("height", function(d){
        return d.height;
      });

     //plot axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

     //plot line
    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .style("stroke", "red")
      .attr("d", line);

     //plot line overlay
    svg.selectAll(".clipped")
      .data(d3.range(clips.length))
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "clipped")
      .attr("clip-path", function(d){
        return "url(#area-" + d + ")";
      })
      .style("stroke", "green")
      .style("stroke-width", "3")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr("d", line(data));
    
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you Mark this was exactly what i was searching for! And thanks to this answer and some research I did to comprend better your code, I also understood better how enter() works and how much power this function has in d3. 
P.S Sorry for my bad english, and thank you for the code formatting i really appreciate your help and i will try to help more as well on stackoverflow :-)